# Joins - get row from one table then get all rows that match in another table? but first table matching row should not be repeated

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables. Gallery and Joins.

```
Gallery
id | title
 1 | Dog Gallery
 2 | Cat Gallery

Joins
id | gallery_id | picture_id
 1 |      1     |     100
 2 |      1     |     101
 3 |      2     |     56
 4 |      1     |     102
```

I want to get id, gallery title from gallery - where id is equal to a specific id but also get all of the rows from joins where gallery id equals a specific gallery id.

So for above if the id was 1. I would want the dog gallery from gallery and picture_ids 100,101 and 102 from joins.

now the problem is that gallery title should comes one time.
result is title=dog gallery picture_id=100,title=dog gallery picture_id=101,title=dog gallery picture_id=102 i need the result like this
title=dog gallery picture_id=100,picture_id=101 and picture_id=102

Comment: Add the expected result as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to have all the IDs as string

```
SELECT G.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT P.picture_id ORDER BY P.picture_id DESC SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM gallery as G
LEFT JOIN pictures as P ON P.gallery_id = G.id 
GROUP BY G.id;
```